# WordPress Custom Select Query

Tags: mysql, wordpress, select

I really don't know enough about MySQL queries and it's showing.

I have a custom field set for every post. The custom field stores the posts source URL in a key called "source_url".

I have it working with the below WP_Query parameters, but **it's incredibly slow**. Keep in mind it's possible to 50+ urls to search for.

So, given an array of source URL's, I want to fetch the matching posts.

For example, here is what I currently have that's slow in WP_Query:

```
// var_dump of $urls array (this could be 50+ urls)
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(42) "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FMghvnqDhT8"
  [1]=>
  string(42) "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RY-yUFpXTnM"
  [2]=>
  string(58) "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nIm2dnyJ1Ps&feature=related"
  [3]=>
  string(42) "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NoCtRQlJAqM"
  [4]=>
  string(57) "http://holidaycustoms.blogspot.com/2012/08/busy-week.html"
  [5]=>
  string(42) "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DcZvg197Ie4"
  [6]=>
  string(42) "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7P3UEbLmLuo"
}

// Build Media Query
$meta_query = array(
    'relation' => 'OR'
);
foreach( $urls as $url ) {
    $meta_query[] = array(
                        'key'       => 'source_url',
                        'value'     => $url
                    );
}

// Get 20 matching posts from a category set by a variable
$args = array(
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'   => 20,
    'orderby'          => 'rand',
    'cat'              => $cat_ID,
    'meta_query'       => $meta_query
);
$posts = get_posts($args);
```

What I'm looking to do is replace the above code with a custom query select, [which I have read is much faster than WP_Query](http://wordpress-hackers.1065353.n5.nabble.com/Expensive-meta-query-Is-there-a-better-way-td38467.html).

**But I don't know enough about MySQL or the WP database to build the custom select query. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Before you start smashing around with WordPress database internals, it might make be a good idea to learn more about MySQL and SQL in general. The basics of proper SQL syntax aren't too complicated, where once you figure out the three basic commands, `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` you're well underway.

Comment: Isn't there a `relation = 'OR'` missing in your code? I thought the default relation was `AND`

Comment: @dualed: Yes your right, I added that. I updated question too. It seems to make the process somewhat faster, but it's still quite expensive on the server.

Comment: Are you using a caching plugin? It may help your performance before you start digging into SQL.

Comment: @DrewBaker I was asking because the query should not be working with an `AND` relation for more than a single URL. For a single URL (where the relation would not matter and with which you have probably been testing) there should be no difference in speed and for more than one `AND` should actually be faster, even though it will most likely always return an empty result. I don't know why you experienced a performance increase, but it's most likely due to other factors and not this.

Answer (score 0):

In the post you linked yourself, the first reply already states that

> [...] the default schema doesn't even have an index on the value column

Which is far more severe a problem than any you would have with a query generator, because without an index the DBMS has to traverse the whole table and compare strings of each field.

Adding an index is fairly easy with an appropriate management tool like [PHPMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net). The offending table you will need to add an index to is called `wp_postmeta` and the field that needs an index is `meta_value`, and the index type should be `INDEX`.

Adding an index is transparent and does not affect wordpress other than in performance. It could take some time though since, well MySQL needs to traverse the whole table. Also, because you are indexing string data, the index will be quite big.

---

You should also try using appropriate structures for your query. You are currently using a big `OR`ed selection with different values but always the same field. There is a construct for just that, and it's called `IN`.

```
...
// Build Media Query
$meta_query = array();
$meta_query[] = array(
    'key'       => 'source_url',
    'value'     => $urls,
    'compare'   => 'IN'
);

// Get 20 matching posts from a category set by a variable
..
```

(Untested. I actually never did this, [Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters))

The performance gain would be negligible compared to adding an index I assume, but your code would become a lot simpler.